# How to check if a Tooltip is set on a Control

Tags: c#, winforms, tdd, tooltip, nunit

Let's say I've got the following code in a (part of a) method:

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
Control ctrl = new Control();
tip.SetToolTip(ctrl, String.Empty);
```

I want to assert in a test that in a particular situation that `tip` is associated with `ctrl`. The following call does not suffice:

```
Assert.AreEqual(String.Empty, tip.GetToolTip(ctrl));
```

This call succeeds whether or not the above method-body was executed. I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

```
ToolTip t = GetTooltipForControl(ctrl);
Assert.IsNotNull(t);
```

`GetTooltipForControl` should return null when no tooltip is associated with the control, and should return the ToolTip instance when it is. Can this be done?

Reminder: I personally only require this logic for unit testing / regressions testing in order to fix a bug in a TDD fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find any way how to check if tooltip has been set, if had been set empty. A way how to do it could be to create custom control and use it instead of standard control.
Like:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public bool isTooltipSet
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void SetToolTip()
    {
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.SetToolTip(this, string.Empty);
        isTooltipSet = true;
    }
}
```

You could then check it with:

```
CustomLabel lbl = new CustomLabel();
lbl.SetToolTip();
Assert.AreEqual(true, lbl.isToolTipSet);
```

Why do you need do set and check empty tooltip? maybe there is better way to do it. Maybe you could set some text, but set the `Active` property of tooltip to false

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.Active = false;
Control cc = new Control();
tt.SetToolTip(cc, "text");
Assert.AreEqual("text", tt.GetToolTip(cc));
```

EDIT:
One more idea that is not so super hacky and needs less refactoring. You could make extension method for setting tooltip, in which you would store the tooltip text into `Control.Tag` property.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetToolTip(this Control ctrl, ToolTip tt, string text)
    {
        tt.SetToolTip(ctrl, text);
        ctrl.Tag = text;
    }
}
```

And then assert:

```
Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, (string)ctrl.Tag);
```

`(string)ctrl.Tag` will be null when extension method `SetToolTip` was not called, and `sting.Empty` when it was called with `string.Empty` parameter

Comment: I'm not explicitely setting String.Empty. I used it in this example as `ToolTip.GetToolTip` will return String.Empty, regardless if I used `ToolTip.SetToolTip` or not. I'm looking for a way to see if the control has a `ToolTip` assigned to it, as we also make use of `ToolTip.ToolTipTitle`.

Comment: @Xilconic Then making a custom control might be the best solution here. Other that come to my mind are way too hacky

Comment: @Xilconic added one more solution that could help

Comment: The alternative might indeed work in a different environment, but we just happen to already use the `Tag` property for something else. But a good suggestion non-the-less :)

Comment: What type is this another thing? You could add both in single class. But that could mean lots of refactoring again...

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't know. I've only been informed to not put stuff in the Tag, because 'it is used by something else already'. And as this checking is only relevant to me in a few unit tests, I don't think refactoring might be an option for me in this case :(

Comment: Well, then i think only "hacky" solutions are left. What properties are you not using? do you need to be able to Tab into controls? if not, then set `Tabstop` to `false` and use `TabIndex`. No background image? You can use `BackgroundImageLayout`. `CanFocus`, `CanSelect`, ... These are not 'clean' solutions, but it will work...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, they are also work-arounds. But as I'm only needing the knowledge of 'is a tooltip attached to a control' for testing purposes only, implementing any of these suggestions would cause me to create code to appease the innards of a few unit tests. The extension wouldn't be used by any business logic what so ever. But for people that require this knowledge in their business logic, I think the `CustomLabel` suggestion is the most fruitful. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` should check that properly:

```
Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tip.GetToolTip(ctrl));
```

Comment: dont think it will work, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tip.GetToolTip(ctrl))` is true no matter if the tooltip is set or not - `GetToolTip` returns empty string in both cases.

Comment: The reason is that your first doesn't actually set the tooltip, you've created an instance of `ToolTip` but you didn't configure it with text. `tip.SetToolTip` configures the control properties.

Comment: @Andrew: `ToolTip.GetToolTip` will always return `""` if the `Control` passed as argument has not been used to call `ToolTip.SetToolTip`. As we also use `ToolTip.ToolTipTitle` as well, an empty string is actually perceived as valid input (but will be turned into `" "` in order to have the tooltip showing with the Title; Bit hacky though, but that's technical debt for ya :( )